# Understanding singletons class in Java

Tags: java, serialization, singleton

When reading Effective Java I found that the most useful approach to implement singletons is just using `enum`s with single `INSTANCE`. But in case we need to make it a class, according to some of his susggestions the perfect serializable thread-safe ***singleton class*** would look like this:

```
public class SerializableSingletonClass implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int value;
    private String name;

    private SerializableSingletonClass(int value, String name) {
        if( value < 0 ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value may not be less than 0");
        this.value = value;
        this.name = Validate.notNull(name, "Name may not be null");
    }

    private static class SerializableSingletonHolder{
        public static final SerializableSingletonClass INSTANCE;
        static {
            INSTANCE = new SerializableSingletonClass(0, "default");
        }
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws InvalidObjectException{
        throw new InvalidObjectException("proxy required");
    }

    private Object writeReplace(){
        return new SerializationProxy(this);
    }

    private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public SerializationProxy(SerializableSingletonClass ignored) { } //Here is the question

        private Object readResolve(){
            return SerializableSingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I got he proposed to just replace serialized instances with one that's used currently.

So, why do we ever need to make singletons serializable in the owing that their serial form would not be ever used. We just throw it out and replace deserialized instance with the current one.

To me the problem of implementing serializable singletons looks like only a theoretical one. Accoring to what I said, deserializing singleton doesn't make much sense (in the case of `enum`s either).

So what did I miss? Couldn't you explain it in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enums are also serializable, just not their fields.

I think it's important to keep it simple and easy to maintain e.g. use a text file if you are going to save it.

I would add a method like save and load to it (possibly with a filename)

```
enum SaveableSingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    String name;
    int value;

    public void load(String filename) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename))) {
            name = scanner.nexLine();
            value = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void save(String filename) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File(filename))) {
            pw.println(name);
            pw.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

creates a file like

```
my-name-is
12345
```

Comment: Yes, but why would we need to serialize `INSTANCE` and deserialize it later? In your example you don't exactly serialize the singleton instance, but persist some useful information into a file. It definitely makes sense. But serializing the `INSTANCE` seems completely pointless to me.

Comment: @DmitriiBundin it only makes sense if you plan to serialize multiple objects e.g. a Map of singletons, but when you deserialize the objects, you would have to set the singletons again.

Comment: @DmitriiBundin when you deserialize a singleton, you get another one. o_O

Answer (score 0):

If you have some field in some other serializable class where you store this singleton instance and want to serialize / deserialize that class, you would always have to mark that field `transient` and make sure to fill it manually on deserialization. If you handle it in the Singleton, you don't have to do this. I guess that is the reason for a serializable singleton.

Comment: Actually, right, but in case of serialization proxy I don't think it's needed. We don't exactly serialize the class, but its proxy. So, default serialization form works pretty well.